# Sass/Scss @mixin for element's selector as well

Tags: css, sass

Say I have to have the following CSS:

```
div { }
div:hover {}
div:active {}
```

Is there a way to create a `@mixin` so that I can use

```
@mixin myAmazingMixer() {
    // Div stuff
    :hover { // Hover stuff }
    :active { // active stuff }
}

div {
   @include myAmazingMixer
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely!  The one thing you're probably missing is the `&` selector ([which references the parent selector](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand))

```
@mixin myAmazingMixer() {
    // Div stuff
    &:hover { // Hover stuff }
    &:active { // active stuff }
}

div {
   @include myAmazingMixer
}
```

Without the `&`, your `:hover` would be applied to all *child* elements of `div`.

Comment: Well, that was easy! Thanks! I'll vote this in 9min once it lets me!

Answer (score -2):

Create a mixin like : @mixin highlight{color: white;} and then if at all any other element needs to be given a color white u can simply add this mixin to that specific class by mentioning @include highlight

Answer (score -4):

Yes you can do that. You can create a mixin(a css rule) and include it.

Comment: Create a mixin like : @mixin highlight{color: white;} and then if at all any other element needs to be given a color white u can simply add this mixin to that specific class by mentioning